# What is the name of this ruler for Photogrammetry? Where to find similiar ones?

Tags: terminology

i want to measure something in a picture on a plane. To adjust the picture after shooting it e.g. to do lens correction and de-skewing I want to use a calibration ruler as attached.

What is the professional name for such targets and similar ones as below? What is a common source for material like this?

[image]

thx

Comment: Photo ruler. One supplier is [Lynn Peavey](https://www.lynnpeavey.com/product_info.php?products_id=507). Look at forensic/crime analysis supply houses.

Comment: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:50_mm_L_ruler_ty.svg

Comment: Are you sure it isn't called a Bunanupher Scale?

Comment: That... doesn't come up in any google search at all. Are you sure? Can you elaborate? Might there be a different spelling?

Answer (score 1):

It is called an "ABFO#2" ruler. Check out the page [here](http://www.orcforensics.com/BureauABFO.htm). You can also find similar ones following that link.

Comment: it is called a **forensic corner square** according to the link you supplied - the part number is ABFO#2 at that specific manufacturer.

Comment: Actually, you got it wrong, sorry. The "forensic corner square" is the general category or type. See: "The ABFO#2 is the first forensic corner square"... The part number is: "4CSM-WH5x5PL/ORIG". But ... whatever. :-)

Comment: "AFBO" is [apparently](https://www.safariland.com/products/forensics/crime-scene-documentation/rulers-and-scales/abfo-no.-2-photomacrographic-scale-1005951.html) "American Board of Forensic Odontology" — specifically for bite-mark forensics. Crucially, this isn't at all designed for use in "lens calibration and deskewing" as the question requests.